# Xamarin Forms Windows Phone MasterDetailPage - Remove default ApplicationBar icon

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

When using a MasterDetailPage in Xamarin Forms, the Windows Phone renders this as a Panel which displays by hitting an icon on the ApplicationBar. Is there anyway to remove this icon and hookup the panel display event to a different button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the application bar via the Application Context. For example:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var app = (MainPage)((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content;
    var applicationBar = app.ApplicationBar;
    applicationBar.Buttons.Clear();
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: - Where to put the code?, what is "Application Context" ?

Comment: @Best_Where_Gives You need to create a custom page renderer for your page. Details, see here on Xamarin developer (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/contentpage/#Creating_the_Page_Renderer_on_Windows_Phone)